# JavaFx Loading additional FXML into FXML 'template'

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I need to create many different FXML files, and each of these has a consistent layout. Each will have an AnchorPane which will hold seperate content.

Is there a way to load a 'base' FXML file, and then load a second FXML file, and route that data into the first?

For example, FXML #1 has a BorderPane. FXML #2 has a button, texfield, label etc. How do I load #1, and then load #2 as a child of #1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `<fx:root>` element to allow you to add something to a existing element.

You'll need a way to get a reference to the node that should be used as root element and pass it to the `FXMLLoader` when loading the second fxml. You could e.g. use the namespace to get that element using the `fx:id` attribute:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader outerLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("outer.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(outerLoader.load());

    URL inner = getClass().getResource("inner1.fxml");
    // URL inner = getClass().getResource("inner2.fxml");

    FXMLLoader innerLoader = new FXMLLoader(inner);

    // get insertion point from outer fxml
    innerLoader.setRoot(outerLoader.getNamespace().get("insertionPoint"));

    innerLoader.load();

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### outer.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <BorderPane AnchorPane.topAnchor="10"  fx:id="insertionPoint"/>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

#### inner1.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <Label text="Hello from inner 1."/>
    </center>
</fx:root>
```

#### inner2.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <Label text="Greetings from inner 2."/>
    </center>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! The .setRoot() snippet worked like magic and fixed all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

or you can actually include the template file like this

```
<fx:include source="../templates/my_template.fxml"/>
```

Comment: be careful with starting the source with periods - wouldn't interpret the spec as supporting them: _Values that begin with a leading slash character are treated as relative to the classpath. Values with no leading slash are considered relative to the path of the current document._